# Different state for Eloquent model fields depending on current user in laravel

Tags: laravel

I have the model:

```
class Task extends Model {
}
```

with some fields

```
protected $fillable = ['message', 'due_time', 'status', 'etc...'];
```

I've added custom function:

```
public function getEditableStateFor{AttributeName}
```

In my helper function I check that if

```
method_exists($class, 'getEditableStateForField1')
```

than I allow to edit this field depending on boolean value returned from this function.

Example:

```
if( ! $class->getEditableStateForField1() ) {
    return "You can not edit field field1";
}
```

Here is how looks like some functions in `Task`:

```
private function isCreator() {
     $user = Auth::user();
     if($user) {
         return $user->id === $this->creator_id;
     }
     return false;
}   

public function getEditableStateForMessage() {
     return $this->isCreator();
 }

public function getEditableStateForDueTime() {
     return $this->isCreator();
 }
```

Is this a good way to do it or it is very bad design because of hidden dependency on `Auth::user()`?

What is a better way?

I do not want to put this logic inside controllers because this logic propagates to another models and is universal across application.

Comment: Personally, I keep models strictly as a PHP object version of a DB row, usually. Sometimes I just extend a model class with one that implements this extra business logic, but avoid putting it in the model (I think it just makes it less elegant (eloquent)). On the other hand if it works...

Answer (score 0):

I'm like you and like to have Models that contain as much of the business logic as possible while remaining totally free of depencies on the "web" part of the application, which I believe should stay in Controllers, Request objects, etc. Ideally, Models should be easily usable from command line interfaces to the application, from within the Tinker REPL, and elsewhere while still guaranteeing data integrity and that business rules are observed.

That said, it seems the Laravel creators had slightly different ideas, hence the Auth facade being easily available in the model.

What I would likely do is add a parameter of type `User` to the `getEditableStateFor` series functions, and then in turn pass that parameter to `isCreator ($user)` and elsewhere. That also frees you up to be able to allow associated users to edit each other's Tasks if that ever became a desired feature in the future.

Edit: another, perhaps better or perhaps worse, is to have an instance method like `setCurrentUser ($user)` then use `setFieldNameAttribute` methods so that the controller doesn't have to check the editability of fields, keeping that the model's responsibility. Then you could call the `getEditableStateFor` methods, which now check for the current user set by the above method (maybe falling back to `Auth::user()` or throwing a helpful error), inside the setter.